# Scale template background images for a specific breakpoint

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-5

We have a site made using bootstrap 5. Background images were adapted specifically for 2 breakpoints (1920px and 360px),

Is there a way to scale all of the design elements by 30% for a breakpoint like 1536x?

Currently the background images do not scale well, so I was wondering if it's possible to "shrink" everything including images?

Here's a side-by-side example. Left is full 1920px width and right is when viewed in 1536x. The sun is just as big so the logo covers it partially and on the right the arrow no longer points to the call to action button correctly.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to target all elements with `*`, but I'm not sure if this will bring the desired output.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1536px) {
    * {
        transform: scale(0.7);
    }
}
```

You can also exclude elements with [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1536px) {
    *:not(.dont-affect-this-element) {
        transform: scale(0.7);
    }
}
```